# How to find the probability of getting a different card the second time which is not the same as the first time for each individual

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If two men took one card each (i.e., both of them together took 2 cards) from a deck of 52 cards. After they took the cards and saw it, they replaced and reshuffled the cards. Then, the two repeated the same process again. Find the probability of getting a different card the second time which is not the same as the first time for each individual?

**My attempt** :The probability of A drawing first would be $\frac{1}{2}$. Then, there would be two cases, first where he got B's card and the other where he got some other random card that's not his or B's.

$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{52}\frac{51}{51} + \frac{50}{52}\frac{50}{51})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2551}{2652})$

The equation and the cases would be exactly the same when B draws first and the sum i.e. the total probability would come out to be $\frac{2551}{2652}$.

But this isn't even close to the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can assume that $A$ draws first.

Comment: You can rephrase the question as: "If 2 cards are selected (this in the sense that they were drawn the first time and were replaced) and 2 cards are drawn (after that selection) then what is the probability that among them there are no selected cards?"

Comment: @drhab Why can't they draw each other's cards?

Comment: @drhab won't that just be $\frac{\binom{50}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$? I thought the problem is more complex bc you can select the same set of cards but distribute it to the wrong person and thus making a valid selection

Comment: @drhab Yeah, that's exactly what I am thinking

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I supposed (maybe wrong) that both draw cards from the same deck and A and B cannot draw the same card.

Comment: I get the same  answer you got, in a slightly different way.  The total number of ordered pairs of cards is $52\times 51$.  There are $51$ such in which $A$ matches and $51$ in which $B$  matches.  We need to take one back because we double counted the pair in which both match, so there are $2\times 51-1$ bad pairs.  Thus the answer is $\frac {52\times 51-2\times 51+1}{52\times 51}=\frac {2551}{2652}$.  Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: @Satya Yes, that would lead to the answer of Vadim. Can you check whether his answer is (in)correct?

Comment: @lulu I had gotten the answer using your exact approach in my first attempt. I took one test and this was one of the problems. My answer wasnt matching with any of the options so I marked "None of these" but it says I got it wrong. The other options were $\frac{5}{12}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ , $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Those numbers are far too low. It's very unlikely that either will match their card.  They must be interpreting the problem in a different way.  Though it seems pretty straight forward....

Comment: @Satya If these are the options and one of them is correct then my interpretation must be wrong. Sorry. IMV the quoted question is not quite clear.

Comment: @Satya Final comment: I think that your answer is correct.

Comment: @drhab Thanks! I needed this. I was getting confused about my understanding of probability alone in my room. Thanks a lot both of you, drhab and lulu. I will just delete this question in a while

Answer (score 2):

$$
\text{Probability}=\frac{\binom{50}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}.
$$

Comment: Won't we miss the cases in this where A gets B's card and vice-versa?

Comment: The term $\binom{50}{2}$ consider those two cards, extracted in the first time.